# convert apex if statement to formula

Tags: apex, formula, formula-field

I have this if statement in apex i need to implement it in formula field i cant figure it out

```
if($Setup.TimeOff_Setting__c.Work_From_Home__c == true){
  if( (Is_Carryover__c  != true) && (Type__c !== 'Sick')){
    return true;
}
}else if($Setup.TimeOff_Setting__c.Work_From_Home__c == false){
  if( (Is_Carryover__c  != true) && (Type__c !== 'Sick' && Type__c !== 'Work')){
     return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `$Setup` is a valid Apex identifier...most of this syntax seems like it won't compile. Are you sure you don't mean formula to Apex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could have (and should be) optimized which, as a formula, would look more like this:

```
AND(
  NOT(Is_Carryover__c),
  NOT(ISPICKVAL(Type__c,'Sick')),
  NOT(OR($Setup.Timeoff_Setting__c.Work_From_Home__c,
         ISPICKVAL(Type,'Work'))))
```

Note that the NOT-OR part is specifically invoking De Morgan's Laws (`NOT A AND NOT B` is the same as `NOT (A OR B)`).

In Apex Code, it would be:

```
Boolean workFromHomeFlag = Timeoff_Setting__c.getInstance().Work_From_Home__c;
return (!record.Is_Carryover__c && 
         record.Type__c != 'Sick' &&
         !(workFromHomeFlag || record.Type__c != 'Work'));
```